# Foreign key referencing an inner join

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, inner-join

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE problems (pid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE submissions (sid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, pid INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES problems);
CREATE TABLE testcases (tid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, pid INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES problems);
```

Now I want to add the fourth:

```
CREATE TABLE results (sid INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES submissions,
    tid INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES testcases, PRIMARY KEY (sid, tid));
```

I'd like to ensure the "submission" and the "testcase" of each "result" are of the same "problem". Unfortunately one cannot reference a view, so this won't work:

```
CREATE VIEW allowed_results AS
    SELECT sid, tid FROM submissions INNER JOIN testcases USING (pid);
CREATE TABLE results (sid INTEGER NOT NULL, tid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (sid, tid), FOREIGN KEY (sid, tid) REFERENCES allowed_results);
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6.1. How should I solve this?

Comment: Include the `pid` column to the `results` table, & include it in both foreign keys. This way (because `results` have a single `pid`) it can only connect `submissions` & `testcases` when this `pid` is matching. (You might need explicit `UNIQUE` constraints also).

Comment: @pozs But the table would not be in second normal form.

Comment: that's more like a philosophical question. Technically, it *is* in 2NF if you consider `pid` as the part of the primary key too. Which it should be anyway, because it holds the following information: the `sid, tid` pair only considered to be a valid row in `results`, if their referenced tables' have this exact `pid` value. But I admit, it you watch this from a more-like bit-by-bit perspective, it can be considered as a violation of 2NF. Either way, that's the only known method to your problem.